# Angular AOT using isDevMode giving error

Tags: angular, angular2-aot

When using isDevMode() working fine for JIT build, while failed for AOT stating

```
Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'isDevMode', function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function
```

trying to create export function like this but no luck

```
export function isDevModeEnabled() {
   return isDevMode();
}
```

Comment: Also experiencing this issue; would love a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I also encountered this error, and raised it as an issue [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20409). The official response from the Angular 2 development team is that this is not a bug:

> I believe this is an intended behaviour. The solution is to move isDevMode() out of the annotation. (By defining to a variable)

**The official solution is:**

> [...] You will need to set the return value to a variable, and use the variable rather than calling the function when wiring up the NgModule.

Comment: Thanks @ReactingToAngularViews following code works for me
let checkDevMode = false;
if (isDevMode()) {
  checkDevMode = true;
}

Answer (score 0):

A wild guess, but maybe you can try to make the function `public` instead of  anything esle - it helped me with [problems](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11978) when  I tried AOT compile.

Comment: Function is outside of class, so can't add public keyword